# Unable to change element colour in Viewer

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, autodesk-forge

To test out a PoC, I'm trying to colour a selected element red. To do this I have created a class, as below, but nothing happens to the elements when I select them. I've tried a number of the examples around the web (including some which create a mesh proxy for the render proxy and add an overlay) but nothing works.

How do I change the colour for a given element (either `dbId` or `fragId`)? I can't find API documentation for most of this in the Forge API, so I'm flying a little blind.

```js
/* global Autodesk */

import * as three from "three";
import * as uuid from "uuid";

type SelectionChangedEvent = {
    fragIdsArray: number[];
    dbIdArray: number[];
    nodeArray: number[];
    model: object;
};

export default class ViewerInteractionHandler {
    viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D;
    material: THREE.Material;

    constructor(viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D) {
        this.viewer = viewer;
        viewer.addEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
            (e) => this.handleSelectionChange(e)
        );
        this.material = new three.MeshStandardMaterial({
            name: "CustomMaterial",
            color: 0xFF0000,
        });

        this.viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial(uuid(), this.material, true);
    }

    async handleSelectionChange(event: SelectionChangedEvent): Promise<void> {
        this.changeMaterialsForFragments(event.fragIdsArray);
    }

    changeMaterialsForFragments(fragIdsArray: number[]) {
        fragIdsArray.map((fragId) => {
            this.viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, this.material);
        });
        this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
        this.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true); // not sure which it is, trying both
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `viewer.setThemingColor` - see doc [here] (https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.html):

```
viewer.setThemingColor( dbId, color:THREE.Vector4, [, model [, recursive:boolean ] ] ) //starting from Viewer v6.3 you may recursively apply color to child nodes
```

And to remove them try `viewer.clearThemingColors`

*EDIT:*

See live sample [here](https://jsbin.com/vutikej/edit?html)

Comment: See edit - did you see any error message in your browser console?

Comment: That example works fine in my browser, and I was able to play around with it, yet this doesn't work at all in my viewing example. Could there be a problem with the models? I've even tried with the sample rvt model provided in the Forge walkthroughs.

Comment: Ok, so actually I realised I had missed a `new` off the instantiation of `Vector4` which was embarassing, so now _something_ happens, but what happens is that a whole tranche of elements disappear from view when I use `setThemingColor` on a single `dbId`.

Comment: Oh, actually I fixed it, there was a problem with the material I was creating on those elements which was making them disappear. I can now set the colour which is good! Thanks!

Comment: But could you help me understand why setting the material wasn't working?

Comment: Sorry for so many comments, also having a problem where it won't work unless I call `clearThemingColor()` at the beginning, and also am finding that the `recursive` option isn't working.

Comment: See code sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/0c0db2d6426f4ff4aea1042813ed10da17c63554/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Material/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Material.js) and [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/d09ecd51a9dc09606c1fc737d033cf2fab93174d/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Particle/Viewing.Extension.Particle.js) to change material. The recursive option is for Viewer v6.3 and onwards. If you look at my live sample there's no need to clear the colors beforehand.