# Getting fragment ids from a dbid

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm struggling a little with seeming inconsistencies between the type definitions, documentation, and behaviour of the viewer.

I've written a simple extension to colour elements (which I can't get to work anyway, but that's a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56280344/unable-to-change-element-colour-in-viewer/)).

When I try to get the fragments for a given node using the [`InstanceTree#enumNodeFragments`](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Private/InstanceTree/#enumnodefragments-node-callback-recursive) method, I get an empty array:

```js
getFragmentsForNode(dbId: number): number[] {
    const fragments: number[] = [];
    this.viewer.model.getInstanceTree().enumNodeFragments(dbId, (fragId) => fragments.push(fragId));
    return fragments;
}
```

The documentation gives no indication of the expected arguments for this callback, but from online examples I'm guessing the signature is something like the following:

```js
enumNodeFragments(dbId: number, callback: (fragId: number) => void, recursive?: boolean): void;
```

The typescript definition is confusing as it lists `node: any` as the first argument, which implies it might not be an id but something else.

When I run this for any element, I always get an empty array which is a bit baffling, as without access to the fragments I can't really set colours etc..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the issue with a valid dbid and model - see live sample [here](https://jsbin.com/vojipoz/edit?html)

```
viewer.model.getInstanceTree().enumNodeFragments(dbId, fragId=> console.log(fragId));
```

Did you provide a valid dbid?

Comment: I was getting the dbid from a selection event, so it definitely should be valid.